# Remove output-escaping in xslt

Tags: html, dataviewwebpart

tag is added to the text if i set format as **"Text"**. i want to remove this  tag programatically.
Is there any way to convert the string from text format to Rich text format **programatically**.
I know we can do it by clicking the smart tag and selecting format as "richtext", however problem with this is it will not display the  tag in string but its present on the page (check by view source) and it effects my html/css which i want to render. i.e even if i change format it adds extra  to my html which i want to eliminate.

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance

Cheers!!
Ketan

Comment: question is not clear... Please, provide input sample and desired output.

Comment: Alejandro thanks for your response.

sorry above question does not contain "div" tag. read it as "div" tag.

when i bind my text field to data view web part it displays text with div tag. i would to remove this div tag programatically. we can remove this by converting the field to Rich-text, however the div is still present on the page which disturbs my html.
Hope it is clear this time.

Please help its urgent !!!

Thanks,
Ketan

Answer (score 0):

add the following attribute:

```
disable-output-escaping="yes"
```